# failed to install .apk in on adb install (using cmd & Minimal ADB and Fastboot)

Tags: cmd, apk, adb

help me with this :(

[image: picture links]

> ```
> adb: failed to install .apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR: Scanning Failed.: Overlay (apk name) must target Q or later, or be signed with the platform certificate]
> ```

Comment: What version of android is this for? If it isn't at least Q, i.e. android 10 or newer, that that's why the message is showing. If it is then there's a platform certificate problem. Could you tell us which it is, instead of us telling you what your message says?

Comment: i don't know this problem in depth .... it's just that I want to install the theme on my android device, but I tried to install it using cmd / adb ... (My device is Asus zenfone max pro m1,Android 10 WW version)

Comment: I saw the tutorial on YouTube yesterday about how to install themes on this cellphone, because this device has pure android, I have to manually install the theme via installation.

Comment: and I saw them (youtube) installing the theme via adb it was very easy and successful...unfortunately when I tried, it failed...I don't know the details of my problem, only from the picture that I can tell about the problem I'm having.